# hover callback function with on() and binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi im adding some elements dynamically, now im trying to bind and a `hover()` using `on()` but that does not seem to work with a callback function. any ideas?

**jQuery**:

```
$(document.body).on('hover', 'div.settings-container', function () {
     $(this).find('ul.settings-links').fadeIn();
}, function () {
     $(this).find('ul.settings-links').fadeOut();
});
```

the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFeVX/) is simplified.

Comment: @Sushanth-- Did you notice the fiddle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In jQuery, `$(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)` **is just a shortcut for**

```
$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);
```

`hover` is not an event, you need to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead.

```
$('body').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
     $(this).find('ul.settings-links').fadeIn();
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
     $(this).find('ul.settings-links').fadeOut();
  }
}, 'div.settings-container');
```

Comment: this binds the `div.settings-container`, adding it dynamically right?

Comment: @Dejan.S Nope, the event is delegated to the body.

Comment: just to make it clear, even if i add that `div` dynamically it trigger on the hover?

Answer (score 1):

Method "on" uses "hover" as shortcut for both events - mouseenter and mouseleave use event.type to detect them

```
$(document).on('hover', 'a.hover-me', function (e) {
    if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
        alert("show");
    } else {
        alert("hide");
    }
});​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFeVX/3/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use both `.on()` and `hover` event at the same time! :(

As a **fallback** you can use this script:

```
$("div.settings-container").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        alert("Mouse Over!");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        alert("Mouse Out!");
    }
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mFeVX/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try `mouseenter` and `mouseout` to delegate the events instead... It is not possible to use `.hover()` with `.on()` ..

Answer (score 0):

From additional notes on jquery docs on [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes)

> Deprecated as of jQuery 1.8: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for
>   the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler
>   for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to
>   determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not
>   confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which
>   accepts one or two functions.

Thus when you use `hover` with `on`, it assumes you are using this [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) which is

```
A function to execute when the mouse pointer enters or leaves the element.
```

Thus either use,

```
$(document).on('hover', 'ul.settings-links', function (e) {
    if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
        alert("show");
    } else {
        alert("hide");
    }
});​

OR

$('body').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
     $(this).find('ul.settings-links').fadeIn();
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
     $(this).find('ul.settings-links').fadeOut();
  }
}, 'div.settings-container');
```

**You cannot use the `hover` which accepts two functions as parameters.**

Answer (score -1):

check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JzxVT/) out

```
 $('a.hover-me').on({
     mouseenter: function(){
       $('.test').show();
     },
     mouseleave: function(){
      $('.test').hide();
    }
});
```